# Can't import django via windows terminal

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell, command-prompt

I'm trying to import django on my virtualenv, but I always get the same error when I use `import django` it says

'import' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

in English, it means "'import' isn't recognized as an intern or extern command[...]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that sounds like a windows error message, in order to use python, you must be in a python shell, not a windows (cmd/Powershell) shell. so you must first enter the `python` command, then you will be taken to a terminal with a `>>>` bell:

```
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

and then you can run commands like `import csv`

Comment: oh, thx. I was following a tutorial and it hasn't said anything about changing terminals, u rlly helped me lol

Comment: I'll do it in five minutes because the site said so. Also, do you know how can I change directories?

Comment: yes type cd, then hit tab a couple of times. if there is a large list of directories, type a first couple characters then hit tab. once the terminal says the right directory, hit enter. to go up to parent, `cd ..` or even `cd ..\..\..`